# AngularFire browser Refresh gives error page not Found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Scenario is,

Im new to AngularJS and making an AngularJS with AngularFire, I have defined my routing bye using `$routeProvider` ,see below

```
var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', [ 'firebase','ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerLogin.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/home', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerHome.html' , controller:'ForLogout'});
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/singup', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerSinup.html', controller: 'RegisterCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard/godash', { templateUrl: '/Templates/dashboard.html', controller: 'DashboardCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/list', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerList.html', controller: 'customerListViewModel' });
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/detail', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerDetail.html', controller: 'customerDetailViewModel' });
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/googlemap', { templateUrl: '/Templates/GoogleMap.html', controller: 'MapCtrl' });
   // $routeProvider.when('/customer/postdata', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerPostData.html', controller: 'AddPostCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/getdata', { templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerGetData.html', controller: 'GetCtrl', reloadOnSearch: false });
    $routeProvider.when('/victim/getdata', { templateUrl: '/Templates/RiskVictimDetail.html', controller: 'VictimGetCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

this is my login controller

```
appMainModule.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'CommonProp', '$firebaseAuth', function ($scope, $location,CommonProp, $firebaseAuth) {
    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("FireaseURL/");
    loginObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);
    $scope.user = {};
    var login = {};
    $scope.SignIn = function (e) {
        login.loading = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $scope.user.email;
        var password = $scope.user.password;
        loginObj.$authWithPassword({
            email: username,
            password: password
        })
            .then(function (user) {
                //Success callback
                // alert('Authentication successful');
                login.loading = false;
                $location.path('/dashboard/godash')
            }, function (error) {
                //Failure callback
                alert('Authentication failure');
            });
        }
    }])
```

my problem is that, when I refresh my login page by browser refresh, it refreshes successfully, but after login when refresh any page it gives me error

> Page Not Found

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="sampleApp">
<head>
    <title>My new Project</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configure $location to use `html5Mode` (history.pushState), you need to specify the base URL for the application with a `<base href="">` tag or configure `$locationProvider` to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with `requireBase:false` to `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

From : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. Angular requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html file () unless html5Mode.requireBase is set to false in the html5Mode definition object passed to $locationProvider.html5Mode(). With that, relative urls will always be resolved to this base url, even if the initial url of the document was different.

From : https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/$location

Simple example:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="appMain">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerLogin.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/customer/home', {
      templateUrl: '/Templates/CustomerHome.html',
      controller: 'ForLogout'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard/godash', {
      templateUrl: '/Templates/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

appMainModule.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.godash = function(e) {
    $location.path('/dashboard/godash')
  }
}]);


appMainModule.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.home = function(e) {
    $location.path('/customer/home')
  }
}]);

appMainModule.controller('ForLogout', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.home = function(e) {
    $location.path('/')
  }
}]);
```

/Templates/CustomerLogin.html

```
<div>
<button ng-click="godash()">/dashboard/godash</button>
</div>
```

/Templates/CustomerHome.html

```
<div>
<button ng-click="home()">/</button>
</div>
```

/Templates/dashboard.html

```
<div>
<button ng-click="home()">/customer/home</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Read more about `requireBase: false` from https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/$location , i had updated more details in answer.

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399

from this post, i think I need URL rewrites, base tag will not provide solution

Comment: @ZaidMirza i had updated the answer with simple example , which is working, but i had not checked by including firebase lib , i don't think there should be any difference between this code and your code, i think it should work for you also, if you are still facing issue give me your full code , I can check and help you.

Comment: its works within application, but not in browser refresh,e.g suppose when browser contains address http://localhost:port/customer/home. browser refresh will check for home.html instead of CustomerHome.html as routing specified